# callback still doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I wrote post several hours ago, where I have several interesting answers, but I don't uderstand everything and now I can't use that post. So I create one new.

I sill have problem with callback in this code:

```
<div id='temp'></div>
<div id='points'></div> 
<div onClick ="play(1, 1)" id='click'>clickclickclick</div> 

<script>
play(function (addpoints) {
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = addpoints;
}());

function play (choosecolor, randescolor) {
    if (choosecolor == randescolor) {
        if (document.getElementById('points').innerHTML === '') {
            document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=100;
        }
        else {
            var points = function (allpoints) {
                var addpoints = parseInt(allpoints) + 100;
                callback(addpoints);

                document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=addpoints;
            }
        }

        points(document.getElementById('points').innerHTML);
    }
}
```

I uderstand that function callback doesn't send var addpoint with its value to second function, so in second function addpoints is undefined. But I don't understand why addpoints lose its value (but I can show it in div), what callback do and how correct it. Some user gave me advise that I should to choosecolor(addpoints); instead of callback(addpoints); but it still not work.

Comment: Is the DOM ready when you are calling `play()`?

Comment: This code is very confusing. You essentially call `play(undefined, undefined)` which triggers your `if (choosecolor == randescolor)`, presumably by accident. Even if you did pass in `choosecolor`, you never actually execute it. And if `choosecolor` isn't supposed to be a callback, you should at least return something from your anonymous function

Comment: There are parts of your code that are obviously missing in the example. Also you're invoking a callback nowhere in your code. I guess the two parameters for play are supposed to be callback functions, but you never pass a callback function. You are passing a single value to play, which in this case is undefined as it comes from a void function invocation.

Comment: In html I have part when function play get values: like <div onClick ="play(1, 1)" id='click'>clickclickclick</div>. I correct in in all code.

Answer (score -1):

After some thoughts and research. i came accross that i was wrong somewhere. Here is the solution , pass the last parameter - which is the name of the function you want to call back. Now this will work as you want it to work.
Now here i mentioned the third parameter as name of the function i want to call after this function.

```
<div id='temp'></div>
<div id='points'></div> 
<div onClick ="play(1, 1, newcallback)" id='click'>clickclickclick</div>
```

Here i declared a newcallback function which i will call after this method:

```
function newcallback(addpoints) {
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = addpoints; //undefined
});

function play (choosecolor, randescolor,callback) {
    if (choosecolor == randescolor) {
        if (document.getElementById('points').innerHTML === '') {
            document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=100;
        }
        else {
            var points = function (allpoints) {
                var addpoints = parseInt(allpoints) + 100;
                callback(addpoints);

                document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=addpoints;
            }
        }

        points(document.getElementById('points').innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b28yarrv/)

Comment: Assuming this is the logic the OP wanted, and that is most definitely an assumption, you're missing the third parameter in your definition of `function play`

Comment: So I should to add variable addpoint as  third parameter in play()?

Comment: @RGraham , is this edit fine now ? i was missing the third parameter as you said. You were right.

Comment: Welcome, i also created a fiddle for the same. I was just going to post it.